# Why does Pdf text is messed up when I use iTextsharp to read all pages?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use iTextSharp for read pdf file content. First, I write this code to read just from single page:

```
Pdfreader reader= new Pdfreader("a.pdf");
ITextExtractionStrategy Strategy=iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy;
string s=string.Empty;
int i=1;
//for(int i=1; i<=reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
//{
s+=PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, Strategy)+"/n";
//}
reader.Close();
TextBox.Text=s
```

Output is normal. But when I uncomment above lines to assign to string all of the pages, whole content of pdf is messed up after second page(with the one in the first page). Please help me to understand this bug.
P.S. I need LocationTextExtraction method, so please don't suggest me to change the method.

Comment: Instantiate a new Strategy for each `GetTextFromPage` call.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
Pdfreader reader= new Pdfreader("a.pdf");
string s=string.Empty;
int i=1;
for(int i=1; i<=reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy Strategy=iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy;
    s+=PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, Strategy)+"/n";
}
reader.Close();
TextBox.Text=s
```

Tge `Strategy` object collects *and keeps* text snippets of a page. You need to create a new object for every new page.